# ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Not Working Properly

Tags: excel, vba

Vba macro with `ActiveWorkbook.saveas` is set up to run when file Opens. It works if I open file in Excel Browse or "File Explorer", but if I open in Excel Recent screen, macro runs without error, MsgBox shows, but file name is not changed??

```
Sub Save_PO_File

    PON = InputBox("Please enter PO Number to Start Checklist:", Xpos:=2880, Ypos:=1440)
    strNewName = "Rental Checklist PO " + PON
    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path 
    NewName = strPath & "/" & strNewName

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I have tried different ways and still will not work when file opened in Excel Recent screen,

Comment: Can you be accurate with your tags. Remove vb.net and replace with vba. This will mean the VBA users on the site will be able to see it, and you're more likely to get a reply.

Comment: Instead of `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName`, shouldn't it be `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath`? You havent declared a variable called `NewName` in the sample you posted.

Comment: `NewName` was in code but pasted in badly. I've edited to help its visibility.